# Store a string with quotes (") in JAVA

Tags: java, compilation

Tried to store `"\"the Dolphin\""` using this but it isn't working.

```
String s=""\"the Dolphin\""";
```

Comment: `String s="\"\\\"the Dolphin\\\"\"";` → `"\"the Dolphin\""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String s="\"\\\"the Dolphin\\\"\"";
```

you have to **escape** special chars via \

Answer (score 0):

`"` and `\` are special characters in String literal

- `"` is used to mark start or end of string
- `\` is used to either

  - create special characters like tabulator `\t` or line breaks `\n` `\r` (and few others)
  - escape other metacharacters to make them simple literals like `\"` will let you use `"` inside string (it will not represent end of string literal now so string like `"hello\"world"` is valid)

So if you want to create literals from special characters you need to escape them with `\`. Same rule applies to `\` itself so if you want to create string which will represent `\` you need to write it as `"\\"` (`\` is escaped with another `\`)

So try with `"\"\\\"the Dolphin\\\"\""`

```
String s = "\"\\\"the Dolphin\\\"\"";
//           ↓ ↓ ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓ ↓ ↓ ↓
//literals:  " \ "the Dolphin \ " "
//finally:     "\"the Dolphin\""
```